# Redirecionamento de domínios

Tags: php, htaccess, apache

Estou com dificuldades de configurar o redirecionamento **Htaccess 301** para um domínio.

O domínio principal é o https://www.webfreela.com

Preciso que as combinações abaixo sejam direcionados ao principal:

- https://webfreela.com
- http://webfreela.com
- https://www.webfreela.com
- https://www.webfreela.com.br
- http://www.webfreela.com.br
- https://webfreela.com.br
- http://webfreela.com.br

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^webfreela.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.webfreela.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Agradeço a todos que poderem me ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, boa noite!

Então colega, acredito que com `mod_rewrite`, a forma correta seria assim:

```
RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dominioantigo.com.br$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.dominioantigo.com.br$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.webfreela.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Olá Wagner, muuto obrigado. O unico domínio que não redirecionou foi o `https://webfreela.com.br` e `https://www.webfreela.com.br` que tem o httpS precisa adicionar alguma coisa?

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser sem usar mod_rewrite?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  webfreela.com
    Redirect    301 /   https://www.webfreela.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

(repetir esse bloco para cada domínio alternativo que deva ser redirecionado para www.webfreela.com. URLs com HTTPS devem trocar porta 443 por 80 e devem ter certificado digital configurado.)

Comment: Olá, tem que ser `mod_rewrite`.